# Pig SchemaParseException: Can't redefine:

Tags: apache-pig, avro, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm using data stored in ***avro-1.7.4*** format and trying to use ***Pig*** for data manipulation.
When trying to LOAD data and then STORE them again I've receive following error:

> ERROR 2116: 
>    Output Location Validation Failed for: 'file:///home/pig/100/test.avro More info to follow:
>   Can't redefine: Employees

Any ideas / suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

---

### UPDATE:

Employees field is in two places of schema:

Partial schema:

```
    {
                       "name" : "Employees",
                        "type" : [ "null", {
                          "type" : "array",
                          "items" : {
                            "type" : "record",
                            "name" : "CheckResponsibleEmployee",
                            "fields" : [ {
                              "name" : "Id",
                              "type" : "string"
                            }, {
                              "name" : "Name",
                              "type" : "string"
                            }, {
                              "name" : "Job",
                              "type" : "Job"
                            }, {
                              "name" : "Time",
                              "type" : [ "null", "Date" ],
                              "default" : null
                            } ]
                          }
                        } ],
                        "default" : null
                      }
```

in another place (but i think this is okay) :

```
            {
              "name" : "Employees",
              "type" : "ResponsibleEmployees"
            }
```

Im just simply running script (with loaded libraries piggybank, avro 1.7.4, mapred, etc):

```
    data = LOAD 'part-m-00000.avro' USING AvroStorage();
    STORE data INTO 'output.avro' USING AvroStorage();
```

---

### Full stack trace

```
    Pig Stack Trace
    ---------------
    ERROR 2116: 
     Output Location Validation Failed for: 'file:///home/pig/100/test.avro More info to follow:
    Can't redefine: Employees

    org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1002: Unable to store alias posdata
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1635)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:575)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1093)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:501)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:541)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
    Caused by: org.apache.pig.impl.plan.VisitorException: ERROR 2116: 
     Output Location Validation Failed for: 'file:///home/pig/100/test.avro More info to follow:
    Can't redefine: Employees
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.InputOutputFileValidator$InputOutputFileVisitor.visit(InputOutputFileValidator.java:75)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOStore.accept(LOStore.java:66)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:64)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:66)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.walk(DepthFirstWalker.java:53)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.InputOutputFileValidator.validate(InputOutputFileValidator.java:45)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.compile(HExecutionEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.compilePp(PigServer.java:1380)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1305)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1297)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.access$400(PigServer.java:122)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1630)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Can't redefine: Employees
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$Names.put(Schema.java:1019)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$NamedSchema.writeNameRef(Schema.java:496)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.toJson(Schema.java:611)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$UnionSchema.toJson(Schema.java:799)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.fieldsToJson(Schema.java:633)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.toJson(Schema.java:620)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$UnionSchema.toJson(Schema.java:799)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.fieldsToJson(Schema.java:633)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.toJson(Schema.java:620)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$ArraySchema.toJson(Schema.java:722)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$UnionSchema.toJson(Schema.java:799)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.fieldsToJson(Schema.java:633)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.toJson(Schema.java:620)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$ArraySchema.toJson(Schema.java:722)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$UnionSchema.toJson(Schema.java:799)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.fieldsToJson(Schema.java:633)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.toJson(Schema.java:620)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$ArraySchema.toJson(Schema.java:722)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$UnionSchema.toJson(Schema.java:799)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.fieldsToJson(Schema.java:633)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.toJson(Schema.java:620)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$UnionSchema.toJson(Schema.java:799)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.fieldsToJson(Schema.java:633)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.toJson(Schema.java:620)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.toString(Schema.java:291)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.toString(Schema.java:281)
        at org.apache.pig.builtin.AvroStorage.setOutputAvroSchema(AvroStorage.java:504)
        at org.apache.pig.builtin.AvroStorage.checkSchema(AvroStorage.java:495)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.InputOutputFileValidator$InputOutputFileVisitor.visit(InputOutputFileValidator.java:65)
        ... 25 more
```

Comment: could you pls provide the schema or relation and your code?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thanks for interest. See my update, please.

Comment: Did you try renaming one of the 'Employees' fields to something else. From error, its apparent that Pig is not happy about reusing the same field in the same schema. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, for suggestion. I've resolved it today. We had to redefine schema, because as you say "Pig is not happy" with reusing the same name for fields referring to records of other types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's about ambiguity of fieldnames in PigLatinSchema. I've solved it by redefining/correcting of avro schema not to contain fields with the same name referring to different types of records.

Comment: I'm having this issue also if the tro fields have the same identical type of record. It seems that Avro cannot understand that the two fields have the same schema and tries to generate it twice